# Comparing lists within lists and counting occurrences

Tags: python

If I have a list of lists `a`, I want a function `f()`

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0,5,6],[0,5,4]]
```

that gives the output:

```
out = f(a)
out
>> {[1,2,3]:2,[0,5,6]:1,[0,5,4]:1]}
```

The order matters too, I need it to be completely similar
I was going to use  `Counter` but it does not work with lists. Sets are also out of the question. Is there some sort of 'easier' method than doing the whole thing from scratch maybe using something like `Counter`?

Comment: When you say "order matters", do you mean that `lists` in the result should appear in the same order as they did in the input?

Comment: The output you show is impossible. Lists aren't hashable

Comment: @MadPhysicist The OP noted that in the question.

Comment: @gmds. Not really. OP implies having code that produces a result but shows none.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I took what the OP said to mean "This is the output I would expect if `Counter` could take `lists`. How can I mimic this functionality?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since dictionary keys can't have mutable objects, you would need to convert them to a tuple (a immutable object), then do `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0,5,6],[0,5,4]]
print(Counter(map(tuple, a)))
```

Which outputs:

```
Counter({(1, 2, 3): 2, (0, 5, 6): 1, (0, 5, 4): 1})
```